# How to use NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords with punctuation

Tags: swift, macos, nsstring, nstextfield

I'm using this code to find the NSRange and text content of the string contents of a NSTextField.

```
    nstext.enumerateSubstringsInRange(NSMakeRange(0, nstext.length),
        options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords, usingBlock: {
            (substring, substringRange, _, _) -> () in
            //Do something with substring and substringRange
    }
```

The problem is that `NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords` ignores punctuation, so that

```
Stop clubbing, baby seals
```

becomes

```
"Stop" "clubbing" "baby" "seals"
```

not

```
"Stop" "clubbing," "baby" "seals
```

If all else fails I could just check the characters before or after a given word and see if they are on the exempted list (where would I find which characters `.ByWords` exempts?); but there must be a more elegant solution.

How can I find the NSRanges of a set of words, from a string which includes the punctuation as part of the word?

Comment: If you want to keep the punctuation you can use componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LeoDabus - the problem with that is it doesn't give me the ranges, which is what I really need from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Richa's answer, I used `componentsSeparatedByString(" ")`. I had to add a bit of code to make it work for me, since I wanted the NSRanges from the output. I also wanted it to still work if there were two instances of the same word - e.g. 'please please stop clubbing, baby seals'.

Here's what I did:

```
            var words:  [String]    = []
            var ranges: [NSRange]   = []

            //nstext is a String I converted to a NSString
            words  = nstext.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

            //apologies for the poor naming
            var nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor = nstext

            for word in words
            {
                let range:NSRange = nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor.rangeOfString(word)
                ranges.append(range)

                //create a string the same length as word so that the 'ranges' don't change in the future (if I just replace it with "" then the future ranges will be wrong after removing the substring)
                var fillerString:String = ""

                for var i=0;i<word.characters.count;++i{
                   fillerString = fillerString.stringByAppendingString(" ")
                }

                nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor = nstextLessWordsWeHaveRangesFor.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: fillerString)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentsSeparatedByString instead

var arr = nstext.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

Output :

"Stop" "clubbing," "baby" "seals

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. `componentsSeperatedByString` doesn't give me the NSRange of the words, just the words themselves - the ranges are the most important part.